# How do I start and stop quartz schedular from my class method? Scheduling in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduling, quartz-scheduler

I am new to spring. I implemented schedular which invokes a method after every 10 sec.
which looks like,

```
<bean id="bidApprovalJob"
class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
      <property name="targetObject" ref="bidApprovalOperations" /> 
      <property name="targetMethod" value="checkExpiredAuctions" /> 
      </bean>
     <!--  Simple Trigger --> 
     <bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
      <property name="jobDetail" ref="bidApprovalJob" /> 
      <property name="repeatInterval" value="10000" /> 
     <!--  5second delay mentioned in milliseconds --> 
      <property name="startDelay" value="5000" /> 
      </bean>
     <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
     <property name="jobDetails">
     <list>
      <ref bean="bidApprovalJob" /> 
      </list>
      </property>
     <property name="triggers">
     <list>
      <ref bean="simpleTrigger" /> 
      </list>
      </property>
      </bean>
```

But, this schedular runs all the time. I want to start the schedular at run time when user click the button and stop it after certain time.

Can I start the schedular from my class method? Can I create instance of schedular in a class and then start and stop that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scheduler, created by SchedulerFactoryBean, has standby() and start()  methods, which you can use to control firing of trigger.

Comment: I want to get the schedular bean in my class. How can I get a bean in my controller class using getbean method? This is dynamic web application. any sample syntax will help. Thank you.

Comment: Give an id to your bean with scheduler (one which is created via SchedulerFactoryBean class) and inject it into any other bean which needs an access to it.

Comment: I dont want to inject it in other bean. I want to create instance of schedular in my class method. so how can I access this bean(Schedular) in my class method?

Comment: Why do you need to instantiate a SchedulerFactoryBean when you can inject it? Are there any special reasons for that?